# What values for RUBY_ENGINE correspond to which Ruby implementations?

Tags: ruby, jruby, macruby, rubinius

The method I know of to detect the Ruby *implementation* (e.g., MRI, JRuby, Rubinius, etc.) at run time is to check the global constant `RUBY_ENGINE`:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts RUBY_ENGINE'
ruby
```

What's a reasonably comprehensive list of known Ruby implementations and their corresponding values for RUBY_ENGINE?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's what I've found so far:

```
| RUBY_ENGINE | Implementation    |
|:-----------:|:------------------|
| <undefined> | MRI < 1.9         |
| 'ruby'      | MRI >= 1.9 or REE |
| 'jruby'     | JRuby             |
| 'macruby'   | MacRuby           |
| 'rbx'       | Rubinius          |
| 'maglev'    | MagLev            |
| 'ironruby'  | IronRuby          |
| 'cardinal'  | Cardinal          |
```

Links for the above mentioned Ruby implementations:

- [MRI](http://www.ruby-lang.org/) (Matz's Ruby Interpreter), the Ruby reference implementation
- [REE](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) (Ruby Enterprise Edition)
- [JRuby](http://jruby.org/)
- [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/)
- [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/)
- [MagLev](http://maglev.github.com/)
- [IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/)
- [Cardinal](http://cardinal2.rubyforge.org/)

Props to Ujihisa for [this blog entry](http://ujihisa.blogspot.com/2009/07/const-rubyengine.html) which had most values.
Others were found by reading [this](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/blob/master/lib/launchy/detect/ruby_engine.rb) and [this](http://rbjl.net/35-how-to-properly-check-for-your-ruby-interpreter-version-and-os).  Still more values have been gathered from other answers here on StackOverflow.  More props to everyone who has contributed!

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
| RUBY_ENGINE | Implementation    |
|:-----------:|:------------------|
| "ruby"      | REE               |
| "maglev"    | MagLev            |
```